# Shape of interface between molecules

Tags: molecules

Two seas do not mix, what are the characteristics of the interface?

If we are trying to draw the molecules together, what would the interface look like?

Comment: _Two seas do not mix, what are the characteristics of the interface?_  could you please expand a bit on this, do you mean two liquids of different densities?

Answer (score 1):

Molecules are composed of atoms. Atoms have a nucleus of protons and neutrons and electrons in [orbitals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital) around them.

[image: orbitals]

> The five d orbitals in ψ(x, y, z)2 form, with a combination diagram showing how they fit together to fill space around an atomic nucleus.

The graph shows the probability density for  various electron orbitals, i.e. the probability one  would find an electron if one measured it at a specific (x,y,z).

The shapes of the  orbitals of individual atoms allow atoms to bind to each other due to spill over electrical fields. For a diatomic [molecule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_orbital) the orbitals will be deformed as far as the single atoms goes but they will still exist.

[image: molecularorbital] [image: molorb]

> Suitably aligned f atomic orbitals overlap to form phi molecular orbital (a phi bond)

There exist large varieties of bonds. A similar picture would hold between molecules, their interface will be shared orbitals if the spill over forces are attractive and the molecules can bind to each other. Otherwise they will keep their molecular orbital shape and bounce off each other if interacting .